# Unable to configure a static IP on 18.04

Tags: server

I have looked everywhere but i'm still unable to resolve this issue

```
naoapp01@naoapp01:/etc/netplan$ sudo netplan apply

Error in network definition /etc/netplan/50-cloud-init.yaml line 8 column 12: expected mapping
```

Here are the contents of the 01-netcfg.yaml

```
# To disable cloud-init's network configuration capabilities, write a file
# /etc/cloud/cloud.cfg.d/99-disable-network-config.cfg with the following:
# network: {config:disabled}
network:
  version: 2
  ethernets:
    ens18:
      addresses: [192.168.1.222/24]
      gateway4: 192.168.1.1
      dhcp4: false
      nameservers:
        addresses: [192.168.1.2,192.168.1.221,8.8.8.8,8.8.4.4]
      optional: true
```

Comment: Hello and welcome to AskUbuntu! Please [edit] your question and post the content of `50-cloud-init.yaml`. As the error says, there's a syntax error at line 8, column 12.

Comment: Please see my answer. Please remember to accept it if it was helpful. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try this slightly modified .yaml file...

Copy/paste the entire text...

Show me any errors during the generate step...

Make sure to keep the indentation, spacing, and no tabs...

```
# To disable cloud-init's network configuration capabilities, write a file
# /etc/cloud/cloud.cfg.d/99-disable-network-config.cfg with the following:
# network: {config:disabled}
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  ethernets:
    ens18:
      addresses: [192.168.1.222/24]
      gateway4: 192.168.1.1
      nameservers: 
        addresses: [192.168.1.2,192.168.1.221,8.8.8.8,8.8.4.4]
      optional: true
```

`sudo netplan --debug generate` # generate config files

`sudo netplan apply` # apply configuration

`reboot` # confirm proper operation